# How to start all the threads simultaneously using ThreadPoolExecuter in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I've written the following code to start 1000 threads simultaneously, but It seems that when I call `submit()` on each iteration, that thread starts and this makes a big time difference between the starting time of the first and the last thread. I wonder if there is a way to just save threads in `ThreadPoolExecuter` and run all of them simultaneously after the for loop?

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecuter(max_workers=1000) as executer:
    for i in range(1000):
        executer.submit(foo, i)
```

Comment: It is not possible to exactly start all threads at once. You can use a "threading.Event" object and let all threads wait for it and set it in main thread after the for-loop for starting them roughly at the same time.

Comment: Remove the for loop then executor.map(foo, range(1000)). Also, 1000 concurrent threads is rather a lot!

Comment: Michael Butscher said, "...roughly at the same time." For 1000 threads, it's going to be _quite_ rough. Especially so if your host has fewer than 1000 CPUs.